# Menu (three dots) doesn't appear in emulator but visible in studio

Tags: android, menu

I am just starting learning Android and have some troubles with creating menu in app.

I tried all options to create menu but no one work for me.

When I run emulator or real device menu doesn't appear. 
I have tried "Ctrl+M" and different devices but it doesn't work.

What is the problem?

My MainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(final Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
}
```

my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.genaepic.p013_contextmenu.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Just do it!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

my main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/item1"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/item2"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/item3"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings4"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/item4"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVnbY.png)

Comment: check this out @Genadiy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the showAsAction tag. Your item that inflates your overflow menu MUST BE `showAsAction="always"`, otherwise menu may hide in devices. An example snippet:

```
   <item
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_drawable"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Setting">
    </item>
```

**EDIT**

You can override the onCreatOption to inflate the menu.

```
  @Override

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

Comment: I changed my tag, but it didn't help.
here what i have
http://dropmefiles.com/WuHOG

Comment: Please first try to change app:showAsAction="always" to android:showAsAction="always".

Comment: overriding the onCreatOption helped me. Thanks a lot))
So what was wrong with method without overriding?

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work because the tag uses it's own implementation of the action bar rather than the framework's implementation. Anyway, if the answer solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick icon next to the answer and upvoting it.

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!

Comment: Okey, thank you!
I can't upvoiting it becouse I don't have enough reputation. Actually this is my first question on stackoverflow and I really thankfull for your answer!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Feel free to ask questions here, but make sure to google your questions before asking. You can ping me anytime on chat or by comment. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu: ");
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: ");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

      case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;

}
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```